# arrays pointers dynamic c++

Tags: arrays, pointers, dynamic

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{

    int numDays;
    double sum = 0;
    double avg;
    cout << "Enter the number of days of sales";
    cin >> numDays;
    double *Sales = new double[numDays];

    for (int i = 0; i < numDays; i++)
    {
        cout << "enter how much you sold for day " << i << endl;
        cin>>*Sales;

        sum = sum + *Sales;

        cout << Sales;
    }

    delete[] Sales;
    avg = sum / (numDays);
    cout << "the sum is" << sum << endl;
    cout << "the avg is" << avg << endl;
}
```

Hi this is the output I'm getting can somone explain why the pointer doesn't need to be incremented? and the proper way of doing the same task with pointers.

```
Enter the number of days of sales2
enter how much you sold for day 0
1
0050CD70enter how much you sold for day 1
2
0050CD70the sum is3
the avg is1.5
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple styles for doing this. You can either index into the array itself:

```
double *Sales = new double[numDays];
for (int i = 0; i < numDays; i++)
{
    cout << "enter how much you sold for day " << i << endl;
    cin >> Sales[i];
    sum = sum + Sales[i];
}
```

Or you can advance a pointer, making sure to keep a copy of the original pointer. In the next example, the destination of `p` creeps along indices of `Sales`. (Make sure *not* to use `delete` on `p` since it wasn't created with a `new`!)

```
double *Sales = new double[numDays];
double *p = Sales;
for (i = 0; i < numDays; i++)
{
    cout << "enter how much you sold for day " << i << endl;
    cin >> *(p++);
}
```

(Technically the parentheses aren't needed in `*(p++)`, and in fact there's a lot of code that uses `*p++` instead).

Comment: hey but why cin >> *(p++); wouldn't that go to index 1?

Comment: Each time `*(p++)` is executed, `p` is incremented to point to the next memory address in `Sales`. If you do `*(p++)` for `i` days, then you have `i` entries in `Sales`. This gives us an "invariant" `Sales - p == i`, an equation which is always true in the code snippet as written. But pointers are a little hard to follow along when reading other people's code. So I just recommend you use the `Sales[i]` syntax.